# How to grab data between hyphens?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

I am trying to grab data between hyphens. For example:

```
EXAMPLE-ABC-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4
EXAMPLE-CBA-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4
```

I need to be able to grab the data ABC-1234 but this length is not fixed. Sometimes, it will be ABC-123. What is fixed is that I need the data after the first hyphen and before the third.

I was given a query that takes out the 24XX4.

```
SELECT code,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(reverse([Code]), '.', '.'), 1))  AS Example1,
         REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE([Code]), '-', '-'), 2)) AS Example2
 
    from [table].[database].[example] 
where code in ('EXAMPLE-ABC-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4, 'EXAMPLE-CBA-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4')
```

But I don't quite understand how it's doing this or how to manipulate in my favor. Or, if parsename is even what I'm looking for with what I need as a result. Would appreciate any help, thank you!

I tried using the parse above but quickly realizing it may not be the correct function. I tried using a substring but not understanding that, either.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    code,
    SUBSTRING(
        code,
        CHARINDEX('-', code) + 1,
        CHARINDEX('-', code, CHARINDEX('-', code, CHARINDEX('-', code) + 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', code) - 1
    ) AS ExtractedText
FROM
    [table].[database].[example]
WHERE
    code IN ('EXAMPLE-ABC-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4', 'EXAMPLE-CBA-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4')
```

Find the position of the first hyphen using `CHARINDEX`

Find the position of the third hyphen. Since `CHARINDEX` gives the position of
the first occurrence of a character you will need to call it multiple times each time starting the search after the previous hyphen.

Use `SUBSTRING` to extract the text between these positions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. As long as the data isn't so large that 1 row per hyphen intermediate pivot would be prohibitive I'm partial to this. Index matching just gets hard on the eyes.

Rationale - Use the builtin string_split to a one row per hyphen in your original string. The ordinal value corresponds to the position of the token. Then use any method of group-wise concatenation you like. When it's less than 5 or so I like max(case ...).

```
create table some_test_data 
  (
    id int,
    original_delimited_string varchar(255)
  );

insert into some_test_data values (1, 'Apple-Pear-Banana-Orange-Kiwi');
insert into some_test_data values (2, 'Dog-Cat-Monkey-Deer-Lion');

with row_explode as (
SELECT *
FROM some_test_data
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(original_delimited_string, '-', 1)
)
select id,
       max(case when ordinal = 2 then value else '' end) + '-' +
       max(case when ordinal = 3 then value else '' end)
  from row_explode
 group
    by id;
```

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PearBanana |
| 2 | CatMonkey |

Comment: Just a reminder, this requires you are running a version of SQL Server which supports indexing for `string_split` (Azure, or SQL 2022)

Comment: @Xedni Good call out

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of different methods to skin this particular cat, here's one - find the positions of the required hyphens and simply remove non-required sections with `stuff`:

```
select string, Stuff(s.v, p3.p - p1.p, 100, '') NewString
from t
cross apply(select CharIndex('-', string))p1(p)
cross apply(select CharIndex('-', string, p1.p + 1))p2(p)
cross apply(select CharIndex('-', string, p2.p + 1))p3(p)
cross apply(select Stuff(string, 1, p1.p, ''))s(v);
```

See [working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RK9DdgSH)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to lean towards JSON for such questions.  Perhaps not as performant as some options, but in my little head, more readable, less prone to error and easier to expand.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Code] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('EXAMPLE-ABC-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4'),
 ('EXAMPLE-CBA-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4')

Select A.[Code]
      ,NewVal = concat(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
                      ,'-'
                      ,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
                      )
From @YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([Code],'json'),'-','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
Code                                    NewVal
EXAMPLE-ABC-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4     ABC-1234
EXAMPLE-CBA-1234-XYZZ-DE-LMNO.24XX4     CBA-1234
```